# Join statement with charts laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I am trying to use a join statement when creating a pie chart but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help me see what is wrong with it? It keeps giving me this error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', and I know the cause is from this part `,date('Y')`. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

This is the original code that I am using:

```
   $users = personal_info::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))
                    ->get();
```

This is the code that I am trying to make but it is not working:

```
 $users = DB::table('personal_infos')->join('evaluations','evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id') ->select((raw("(DATE_FORMAT(personal_infos.created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y')), 'evaluations.recommendation', '=', 'Yes') ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
   $users = DB::table('personal_infos')
      ->join('evaluations','evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id') 
      ->select('evaluations.recommendation','personal_infos.created_at' ) 
      ->where('evaluations.recommendation', '=', 'Yes')  
      ->where('personal_infos.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))  
      ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for replying, yes this is what I wanted, and after trying your code there are no errors, thank you so much but can i check with you why am I getting no results? In my database, the evaluations table have 4 people with recommendation = Yes but no result are being shown

Comment: it returns data matching with current date from personal_infos table. please check that condition  also have data to return

Comment: Or check replacing date('Y-m-d') with date('Y');

Comment: Yup, my personal_info table contain all my users and also I tried replacing with what you said but still nothing happen

Comment: I tried doing a dd($users) and it return me an empty collection

Comment: this is what it return me, object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#369 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }, which i guess it empty

Comment: I tried removing the where clause already and it return results, I guess is the where clause problem

Comment: It seems that the problem come from this part,        ->where('personal_infos.created_at', '=', date('Y')) ,  when I remove this where statement it shows me what I wanted. Thank you so much for your help :)